# why static files are not included?

Tags: django

Static files don't work. I seem to have registered everywhere where necessary. But the problem remains. What could be the catch.

`settings`

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

`urls`

```
from django.urls import *
from . import *
from django.conf.urls.static import *
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf import settings
from blog import views

app_name = "blog"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('create', views.create, name='create')
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

[dir structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRMuF.png)

Comment: Your static assets are in the app folder, you need to place it in base project folder, where `manage.py` is.

Comment: @Ersain my static assets place in app static folder too

Answer (score 1):

You can set `STATICFILES_DIRS` like so:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "./app/static"), 
    ]
    

...

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
```

And make a folder in your app that's called static/images or static/whatever.
[image: static images django]

After you've made the folder, run: `py manage.py collectstatic`

And it should work.

If for whatever reason it doesn work,
[the docs on STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#std-setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) may be able to help you further.